Flatcam creating command uncessesary M6
I create a cnc file from a gerber file, B-cu (bottom copper side).
When trying to mill this with Cancle, I get an M6 error.
Since this is only milling with 1 tool Vshape 20deg 0.1mm, I do not understand why the M6 is generated, and how can I avoid this to be created ?
